# Web Project vs. class library

Tags: asp.net, performance

Is there any performance difference between the two? 
I have a web project that only has some classes, but not UI specific items like aspx pages or ascx controls. Should I consider to move those in a Class Library rather thank keep them as a web project ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, you have phrased you question as if you have a web project without any ASPX or ASCX files.
I assume that what you mean that you have a web project with ASPX files, but also some classes that have no dependency to the ASPX files, and you are wondering if you should extract those classes to a new class library project.

As to the question, should you divide the project up, then that depends.

There is no run-time performance benefit the code in a single project. There might be a minor delay when starting the application, but once the assemblies are loaded, then the performance will be identical.

There might be a small development penalty however. I am of the impression that it takes longer to compile a system, if it is split up into many smaller projects, rather than one big one. But I have no data to back this up.

But I would not use that as a determining factor. The important question is, how is your code best structured.

Is it a larger application, I would split it up to have domain logic in one assembly and the presentation logic (web application) in another. Is it just a tiny application I would not.
Except perhaps if you want to run unit tests on the domain logic, in which case I would split it up, so I have one test assembly that tests the functionality of the domain logic assembly.

Comment: Well the thing is that we have quite a big website (corporate) and it's split in about 15 web projects, and I was arguing with the architect why they created all the 15 projects as web project even if in some of them we have no UI components(so web project with no aspx or ascs files, only clases, helpers, utilities etc.) rather than create a class library project for those who don’t have UI components :).
<br />
Thanks for your answers, I thought there is some performance difference and class library seemed to be simpler = faster to me.

Comment: Argh, that just makes no sense. If the project only contains classes, helpers, utilities, etc. then it shouldn't be a web project, it should be a class library. Not because of performance concerns. Simply because the other stuff is just dead wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no performance difference (or if there is it is very tiny) between a single web project, or a web project and multiple class libraries. Most large applications use the latter to compartmentalise and organise their code. In terms of execution time of each, they are both compiled so they will perform exactly the same